# Perfect team and boss vs. better pay, work, industry?

Tags: salary, job-offer, new-job, job-change

I've been working at my first job out of college for 6 months, and have been offered a job at another company. I'm probably going to accept the offer and leave my current job, but am hesitating because I love my team and boss. I was hoping someone could check my reasoning--I'm pretty sure I'm making the right choice, but I know that I'll miss the people I work with.

Pros for current job:

- Relaxed environment, flexible work hours, easy to work from home
- Awesome boss - he's a good person, a great manager, and I have a lot of respect for him. He has been really kind to me and leaving would feel like a betrayal (to me)
- Very tight team of people I really like, with diverse personalities. We hang out a couple of times a week and go away on trips together.
- Involves managing projects and working with clients. I took the job to build my interpersonal and communication skills, and to get past my shyness.

Cons for current job:

- Not intellectually stimulating. I studied software engineering (and liberal arts) in college, and while I get to do a little bit of programming, I'm not bombarded with interesting problems. I've noticed that my technical knowledge is starting to slip away.
- Poor pay. It's ok for a graduate salary, but at least 10% lower than what my other engineering friends are getting.
- I have no passion for the product or product domain

Pros for new job:

- 'Glamorous' and successful smaller (but secure) company, which purportedly has a good working environment and culture as well
- Almost 40% pay increase (my current salary is pretty low)
- Cool products that would be easy to be enthusiastic (or even passionate) about
- It's a web development job, and I've wanted to try out web development for a while. I feel like it could be the career for me, but at the moment only have an outsider's perspective on it.
- The product is for a creative industry that I'd love to be a part of

Cons for new job:

- I'll miss my team! I might keep up with a couple of them, but it's like losing a group of friends. While I'm shy, I'm definitely a people person and draw a lot of happiness from being around good people.
- Uncertainty of what it'll be like, but that's not a good reason to avoid anything in life!

Leaving seems to be the best career move, and I think I'll enjoy the work more. While I feel sick to the stomach at the idea of disappointing my boss and leaving nascent friendships, I don't think that's enough reason to pass up this opportunity (and that salary jump). From what little I've shared, am I making a sensible choice?

(I also don't plan on making a habit of switching jobs every 6 months)

Comment: Thanks, that seems like great advice. I was happiest in my current job in the earliest weeks when there was heaps to learn, and that has kind of dwindled out recently. If this new job/company is as good a fit as it seems I can imagine myself not going anywhere until forcibly moved!

Comment: I've been a bit profligate with my thanks but I really do appreciate the people who have written answers and commented here. I now feel free to be excited about this new job and company, while also being sad to leave my team. One doesn't have to annul the other; I can be grateful for past opportunities while looking forward to new ones.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you have the answer yourself. Significantly better pay in a secure company, cool and glamorous role, in the area where you want to make a career. Go for the new one.

You may miss your team in the old job but that is pretty much part of everyone's career. Even if you stay back, people in your team will move on at some point. Always happens. You will get to meet new people and form new team at new place. Look forward to that!

Yes your boss will be disappointed initially but if they really care about you, they will eventually happy with your new career choice.

Comment: Thank you! You do make it sound like perfect sense, and it's helpful to have someone else's perspective.

Comment: you are welcome @false_azure.  I had a similar (but not identical ) experience. Leaving the old team and boss was very emotional for me and the team.  It took a while to digest but everybody moved on. The new job did not turn out as glamorous as I thought it would be, but that is a different issue!!

Comment: It's reassuring to know someone else has similar experiences! I'm wary of the glamour too - it's definitely hard to gauge what it will be like to work somewhere based on the company's image and public face, as much as I love the look of this other company.

Comment: If no relocation is involved, OP can even keep in touch with the his former colleagues. I regularly meet with a bunch of former colleagues from a company I worked for years ago...

Comment: @LaurentS. Yes absolutely. I relocated to different city but still my old team visit me when they are in town and I do the same.

Answer (score 1):

PagMax pretty much said what needs to be said.

I would also add that; looking at your list of pros vs cons it looks to me the pros of the new job outweigh your current one and the cons are considerably less in the new job compared to your current workplace.

If it doesn't work out at the new job you are free to find something else.

Comment: Thank you @The Butcher! You are right - looking back at my list of pros and cons it does seem like a bit of a 'no brainer' (I've had trouble separating reason from feelings here)!